# Tomcat EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to better understand how Tomcat handles requests and why my specific issue may be happening.

I am trying to enhance my existing Spring MVC web application with the Netflix Hystrix framework. This involves adding a hystrix-specific servlet to handle requests ending with /hystrix.stream.

Based on the logs (below), this mapping works and the request is being forwarded to the correct servlet. However, the exception that is thrown does not occure in the servlet. I have also tried extending the servlet to add additional logging - but it appears that no methods in the servlet are called. The exception seems to be happening because of some inner working on Tomcat that I am not aware of.

Here is a snippet from my web.xml (note that the rest of my application works fine - this is just concerning requests for /hystrix.stream):

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HystrixMetricsStreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hystrix.stream</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I navigate to loalhost:8080/web-app/hystrix.stream I am forwarded to the Tomcat 404 Error. The following exception appears in tomcat's log file:

```
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG AuthenticatorBase:419 - Security checking request GET /web-app/hystrix.stream
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG WebappClassLoader:1582 - loadClass(com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.metrics.eventstream.HystrixMetricsStreamServlet, false)
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG WebappClassLoader:1598 -   Returning class from cache
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG RealmBase:617 -   No applicable constraints defined
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG AuthenticatorBase:501 -  Not subject to any constraint
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG [localhost]:449 - Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/404.htm]
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG Http11Processor:986 - Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:99)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:952)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG Http11Protocol:645 - Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper@56a7cbf2:129bf96a[TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256: Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=53783,localport=8443]]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG LimitLatch:126 - Counting down[http-bio-8443-exec-1] latch=4
2014-04-16 15:53:22 DEBUG Http11Processor:986 - Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:99)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:952)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Has anyone encountered something like this before? As I mentioned, my application works fine - this only occures for /hystrix.stream. I've used the Chrome Postman plugin to add the Accept and Content-Type = application/json headers to the request - both without success. As far as I know, requests to this servlet do not have any header requirements

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know anything about Netflix Hystrix, but it seems that the problem is most likely that the client is killing the connection or sending something the server doesn't understand causing it to kill the connection.  I would start there.

Comment: gettings this in the logs of a grails project. Everything works fine though.....

Answer (score 1):

issue message is very clear, your request head is not corrent.

```
        byte chr = 0;
    do {

        // Read new bytes if needed
        if (pos >= lastValid) {
            if (!fill())//read request content
                throw new EOFException(sm.getString("iib.eof.error"));
        }
        // Set the start time once we start reading data (even if it is
        // just skipping blank lines)
        if (request.getStartTime() < 0) {
            request.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        chr = buf[pos++];
    } while ((chr == Constants.CR) || (chr == Constants.LF));
```

above is the source code of tomcat in InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine
 - *. first time in the while function will be read content (8*1024).
   [usually your header won't be so long]

---

- *. after you read request content, the code will be check the first charactor of '\r\n'

---

- *. so if your request content won't be contains this charactors, will be throw EOF exception

---

- *. then the header paser is faill, so the web container don't know the Servlet method, so your servlet won't be called.

---

i think the server is ok, the problem is appeared in Chrome Postman plugin, please check the header